# Use latitude and logitude to create a grid representing zones?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a module for a transport app.

My boss gave me this task: We have a class called `CitizenRequest` where there's an attribute, called `PointPath`, which stores the latitude and longitude of a citizen's location.

This data is stored in a JSON file in a MongoDB database.

What I have to do is: Take this JSON, find the minimum `PointPath` (or else, minimum latitude and longitude), the maximum, and use this to positions to make a square, which will represent our area of transport.

Now, I have to divide this square into other mini squares, and each one of these will become a "zone". This zone will then have an ID, and must be stored into another collection.

The purpose of this collection should be to store how many requests we have for each zone. So, for example, we will see that in the zone with ID=149, we have X requests.

To do so, I should create an algorithm that analyzes latitude and longitude to understand in which zone it falls.

I know this may sound pretty difficult. Still, I have absolutely no idea how to implement this. So I'm asking you if you have solutions or ideas. I don't really think I must use APIs to do so, I think it just requires some logic behind it. Any help?

Comment: _...find the minimum PointPath..._ relative to what?  When the requirements are clearly defined, try drawing a picture to visualize what needs to be done.  Use that to help determine the data structure(s) that are needed, to be able find the zone where a `PointPath` is located.

Comment: This question is very broad but it sounds like you're looking for something like a [QuadTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Comment: Also, I don't think this question has anything to do with MongoDB. Where you're storing the requests doesn't really have anything to do with how you group them into zones.

Comment: @AndrewS relative to the JSON. I need to find the minimum lat and long, the maximum lat and long, and use those two to create a square. I said PointPath to be a little brief, but also explained it just after. However, thing is this is a task abnormally new to me, so i don't really know what datastructure would fit this situation

Comment: @DavidConrad you're right, i wanted to be a little more specific on the problem i'm facing, but without all the infos it wouldn't be understandable. I'll look into quadtrees

Comment: Clarify if the zones need to be of equal size, or adapting to the data (small in areas where there are a lot of points, big in areas where are only a few points)

Comment: yeah, they need to be of equal size. I have to use this in an Arima forecasting algorithm, to have a forecast of how many requests i could have in that specific zone based on the past requests

Comment: So, where exactly are you facing issues? If you are having trouble finding an "algorithm" to do that, you pretty much described the algorithm you need in your own words already, all you need to do is formulate the same, but not in English, but in Java.

Comment: Well, I explained my problem, but it is easier said than done. For example, how could i make a "square" out of these informations? Because i have to make a square in an abstract way. What logic should i use to understand in which zone a point falls? If it were that easy i would not have made that question

Comment: Just to be pedantic, a region defined by an "upper left" and "lower right" pair of latitude and longitude values isn't a square, since lines of longitude curve, but it is approximately square over small areas, and can be thought of that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume docs contain points like this:

```js
{"citizenID:"C2", loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -76.738988, 39.960921 ] }}
```

then something like this will capture locations in squares inside the bounding rectangle:

```js
// First, scan the whole collection to get topleft and bottomright max points:
c=db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:null,
              L: {$min: {$first: '$loc.coordinates'}},
              R: {$max: {$first: '$loc.coordinates'}},
              T: {$max: {$last: '$loc.coordinates'}},
              B: {$min: {$last: '$loc.coordinates'}}
             }}
]);
d = c.next();

var leftLon = d['L'];
var topLat = d['T'];
var rightLon = d['R'];
var bottomLat = d['B'];

var incr = 0.01;  // this is size of square.  0.01 is 1km.                                       
var totSqr = 0;

// Left to right, top to bottom:                                                   
for(var lon = leftLon; lon < rightLon; lon += incr) {
    for(var lat = topLat; lat > bottomLat; lat -= incr) {

        // Make a square:                                                          
        var coords = [];
        coords.push( [ lon, lat ] );
        coords.push( [ lon+incr, lat ] );
        coords.push( [ lon+incr, lat-incr ] );
        coords.push( [ lon, lat-incr ] );
        coords.push( [ lon, lat ] ); // must close loop!                                 

        c = db.foo.aggregate([
            {$match: { "loc": { $geoWithin: { $geometry:
                              { type: "Polygon", coordinates: [ coords ] } }}
                     }}
            ,{$group: {_id:null, n: {$sum:1}}}
        ]);
        d = c.next();
        if(d != null) {
            print("square region " + lon + "," + lat + ": found " + d['n']);
            // optionally insert the data somewhere as the OP notes.  You can
            // create the zone ID with an incrementing number e.g.
            // db.results.insertOne({"zone": "Z"+(zid++), n: d['n']});
        }
        totSqr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is something i can absolutely work on!

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase,so I understand correctly.
You have one big square which is your valid area (area of transport) and in this square you have a grid, where you try to see where the most requests come from.

First lattitude and longlitude values Look confusing and nothing saying at first: 10,000001 20,002567.
Change that, make it human readable.

If I unverstanden correctly, you need to start and find your point 0.

If you Think of your valid area as a square it would be the bottom left most point. If it is 5.0002345, 10.124567 you would subtract that value of all other values. 5.0003345 10.124567 => 0.0001, 0 so a little bit heigher, than your startingpoint.

Now its way easier to find all the requests in your valid zone. You would take all the points and plot them in an easy x/y plot. Well the implementation I dont know about your dev setup.

I would recomend an simple KNN algorhytmus, to Cluster the request. Maybee the plot itself will be sufficent.

Comment: I think you understood almost everything. I have to create this grid (but it's only datas, i mean, nothing graphic in this). I have to take the min and max lat and long to calculate a square, which will be my area of transport. Then, divide it in a grid, assign an id to each zone, so for each requests that will come later i could analyze it and say "ok, this is the latitude, this is the longitude, so it falls into the zone of id X".

Comment: I have an really simple idea.

Comment: Lattidude and lognitude are alreay x/y axis and you want to group them togheter. Just round them up or down to the sie you need them.

Comment: So if you have a 0.01 difference thats  1.11 km.

Comment: Just round the coordinated to their x.xx point, so you will know how many requests come from this square and so on.